# Powershell - Unable to retrieve active directory attribute after clearing it

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am clearing an AD attribute for a computer.
I then try to change that attribute to some value. However the attribute seems to no longer exist when I look at the properties for that AD object:

```
function clearAttribute
{
    $directorySearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
    $directorySearcher.PageSize = 100
    $directorySearcher.SearchScope = [System.DirectoryServices.SearchScope]::Subtree
    $directorySearcher.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=computer)(cn=computerName1))"
    $result = $directorySearcher.FindOne()
    if ($result.Properties.Contains("netbootmachinefilepath"))
    {
        $directoryEntry = $result.GetDirectoryEntry()
        $directoryEntry.Properties["netbootmachinefilepath"].Clear()
        $directoryEntry.CommitChanges()
    }
}

function setAttribute
{
    $directorySearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
    $directorySearcher.PageSize = 100
    $directorySearcher.SearchScope = [System.DirectoryServices.SearchScope]::Subtree
    $directorySearcher.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=computer)(cn=computerName1))"
    $result = $directorySearcher.FindOne()
    if ($result.Properties.Contains("netbootmachinefilepath")) ###THIS IS FALSE!###
    {
        $directoryEntry = $result.GetDirectoryEntry()
        $directoryEntry.Properties["netbootmachinefilepath"].Value = "someValue"
        $directoryEntry.CommitChanges()
    }
}
clearAttribute
setAttribute
```

**EDIT:** Turns out this attribute can be either non blank or deleted (it can't be blank). After "clearing" it, it will have to be recreated if you want to update the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I incorrectly assumed that it's impossible to set the value of the property if $result.Properties.Contains("netbootmachinefilepath") = FALSE.
This is not the case.
$result.Properties.Contains("netbootmachinefilepath") = FALSE just means that the value is null (or maybe also that the property doesn't exist?).

If you just remove the if statement as shown below, the code works:

```
function setAttribute
{
    $directorySearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
    $directorySearcher.PageSize = 100
    $directorySearcher.SearchScope = [System.DirectoryServices.SearchScope]::Subtree
    $directorySearcher.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=computer)(cn=computerName1))"
    $result = $directorySearcher.FindOne()

    $directoryEntry = $result.GetDirectoryEntry()
    $directoryEntry.Properties["netbootmachinefilepath"].Value = "someValue"
    $directoryEntry.CommitChanges()
}
```