# Using dsmod To Set netbootmachinefilepath Attribute To Blank

Tags: powershell, batch-file

Is it possible to use `dsmod computer` to set `netbootmachinefilepath` ?

I'm unable to use the ActiveDirectory commandlets, and `System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry` doesn't let me clear the value, it only lets me delete the attribute (see [Powershell - Unable to retrieve active directory attribute after clearing it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27032963/powershell-unable-to-retrieve-active-directory-attribute-after-clearing-it)).

It seems as though dsmod is my only hope but it only has a few attributes which you can change.

**UPDATE:**
Seems as though this attribute can be either non blank or deleted (it can't be blank).
I'll have to work out how to recreate the attribute after it has been "cleared".
When I use the Active Directory GUI to clear the value and then read the value using Powershell, it says the attribute doesn't exist. I therefore can't use Powershell to update the value as it has been deleted. However I can use the AD GUI to update it. So logically the GUI must actually be recreating the attribute when I "update" it.

**UPDATE:**
I incorrectly assumed that `$result.Properties.Contains("netbootmachinefilepath") = false` meant that the property doesn't exist. `$result.Properties.Contains("netbootmachinefilepath")` equals false if the property exists and its value is null.

`System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry` will let me clear a value and not delete it as seen in my other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27032963/powershell-unable-to-retrieve-active-directory-attribute-after-clearing-it/27808393)

Comment: Could you use the [ADSI](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4231.working-with-active-directory-using-powershell-adsi-adapter.aspx) adapter instead? Do a search for the object using LDAP and then set the attribute to $null or some other value that way? Why do you need to clear it first are you doing something else to it?

Comment: All I want to do is set netbootmachinefilepath to blank and that's it. I'll have a look at the ADSI thing you're talking about. Thanks.

Comment: Hey Matt, ADSI doesn't help me either. I tried PutEx with the first parameter equal to 1 to clear it, but that deletes the attribute. I tried using 2 to update it with an empty string, but that throws an exception.

Comment: If I use the Active Directory GUI to clear this value, and then try to read it using Powershell code, it throws an exception saying that the attribute doesn't exist. It seems as though it's impossible to have this value blank, it's either non blank or it's deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example using ADSI that will clear the attribute `netbootMachineFilePath`.

In this example, we will first find the computer object in the given domain, then we will retrieve the value of netbootMachineFilePath. If it not clear, we will use the method `PutEx` with the first parameter set to 1 which means clear. Then we will just save the modified object in the AD.

```
function Clear-NetbootMachineFilepath
{
    param([Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string]$Domain,
          [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string]$Computer
         )

    $obj = $domain.Replace(',','\,').Split('/')
    $obj[0].split(".") | ForEach-Object { $domainDN += ",DC=" + $_}
    $domainDN = $domainDN.Substring(1)

    $ldap = "LDAP://"+ $domainDN
    try
    {
        $search = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher([ADSI]($ldap))      
        $search.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=computer)(cn=$Computer))"
        $search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("netbootmachinefilepath") |Out-Null
        $result = $search.FindOne()
    }
    catch
    {
        write-error $_.Exception.Message 
    }

    $ADS = [string]$result.Properties["adspath"]
    $netboot = $result.Properties["netbootmachinefilepath"]
    if ($netboot -ne $null)
    {
        $machine = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry $ADS
        $machine.PutEx(1,'netbootMachineFilePath', "")
        $machine.setinfo()
    }
}


Clear-NetbootMachineFilepath mydomain.ad.local testcomputer
```

**EDIT**

Some references with documented options:

DirectoryEntry can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directoryentry(v=vs.110).aspx) however as you mentioned, PutEx and SetInfo are not documented there, for this, you need look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746504(v=vs.85).aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746506(v=vs.85).aspx).

Finally, the value 1 passed as argument is Clear as mentioned [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa772282%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Delete is 4.

**Additional Edit**

I think I understand what's going on about the Attribute being "deleted" part.
In fact the attribute is not deleted from the AD, it's just not available when retrieved via the Search mechanisms or via the IADs::Get and GetEx methods. GetEx in fact returns `The directory property cannot be found in the cache.`

The property is still there, and cleared, and you can see it via ADSIEdit.

I've added a few lines after clearing the property from the code above:

```
        $machine = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry $ADS
        $machine.GetEx('netbootMachineFilePath')
```

This returns: `The directory property cannot be found in the cache.`

However, I can set something back in that property:

```
        $machine = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry $ADS
        $machine.Put('netbootMachineFilePath', "Hello World")
        $machine.setinfo()
```

And this works, the property is updated and visible in ADSIEdit. Further searches or calling the code above to clear it, will find it.

Comment: Hi Micky, that deletes the attribute rather than clearing it.

Comment: Also I can't see any PutEx() or SetInfo() methods documented for System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry ?

Comment: It seems like the PutEx() and SetInfo() are working as they don't throw an exception and it does delete the attribute, just wondering why they aren't documented on msdn.

Comment: Thanks for the references but the problem still remains that it deletes the attribute rather than clears it.